# Tkinter. How to change the background color of LabelFrame title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to set a white background color of the `LabelFrame` title. I'm working on Tkinter in Python 3.6

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZQh3.png)

Comment: Hi, stackoverflow isn't a solution providing site. Kindly share what you have tried and where you stuck at, for better responses. To improve your chances for a better response kindly have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify your own widget to use as the `LabelFrame`'s "label" — this mean, for example, you could create a separate `Label` widget with the text attributes you want, and specify it when creating the `LabelFrame` via the `labelwidget=` option:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x75')

label = tk.Label(root, text='Life, the universe and everything?', fg='white',
                 bg='blue')
lable_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, labelwidget=label)  # Use custom label.
lable_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

w = tk.Entry(lable_frame)
w.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]